# How can I add an offset voltage at the input of an instrumentation amp?

Tags: analog, instrumentation-amplifier, input-offset-voltage

I want to measure the voltage of an H-Bridge Sensor. However, due to the manufacturing process, the bridge has an offset several times larger than the useful signal (it can easily measured by inverting the bridge sensitivity direction). I want to subtract/add this voltage at the input of the in-amp. Can this be done? If so, how?
I know I could use a summing circuit with a simple opamp like here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#/media/File:Op-Amp_Summing_Amplifier.svg
However, using an inamp would spare me using high precision resistors and loading the bridge with unequal impedances.

Could a similar thing be performed with an in-amp instead of a normal opamp?
Background: The Bridge-Sensor can be switched in direction. E.g. you have 10mV offset and 3mV actual sensor voltage. You reverse the sensitivity so you have 10mV offset and -3mV useful signal. 
To get the signal you measure in reversed and non-reversed mode and subtract (after measuring with an ADC): 10+3-(10-3) = 3+3. You divide by two and get your useful signal, 3mV. I want to specifically add the offset at input level, not at output level, because I am amplifying a little bit of useful and a lot of (useless) offest. 
The sensor I want to use is the HMC1002. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like some variant of a chopper stabilised amplifier  would be useful ... a network of analog switches to do the reversal automatically.

Comment: I got it wrong, I have to look into it first, thanks